# Why im getting only 1515 lines that are exist in html file but when im editing the file i see 1516 lines?

Tags: c#, .net

```
List<int> numberoflines = new List<int>();
            string[] lines  = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                numberoflines.Add(i);
            }
```

I'm looking at the website view source page and see 1516 lines.
When im downloading the html file and read all the lines im getting only 1515.

And im saving the same source view page.

This is the website address im saving it as html file:

[url](http://rotter.net/scoopscache.html)

When im looking this page source view i see 1516 lines when i read this html file only 1515 lines.
I saw now that the last line is empty in the view source but still its line 1516.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you might have a last line which is either blank, endline or an EOF (End Of File) character.